# Sorting list with unknown type in Java

Tags: java, sorting, generics, java-8

I have this list in a method:

```
List<? extends Object> objects;
```

or it can be also:

```
List<?> objects;
```

I wanted to sort it this way, with Java 8 lambda:

```
objects.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2));
```

But it says:

> The method compareTo(capture#6-of ?) is undefined for the type
>   capture#6-of ?

I also tried with generic type:

```
List<O extends Object> objects;
```

But then it says:

> The method compareTo(O) is undefined for the type O

How could I sort a list like this way? I need it in my abstract class, where it recognizes the list field by reflection, and it can sort it.

Comment: You only can compare types that implement Comparable interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

compareTo is available for object that implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.
If you want to do that you should use

```
List<? extends Comparable> objects;
```

For a clean code check @Holger answer

Comment: Thanks! And if it is not extends from that one, will it throw an exception? When I cast the Object to List<? extends Comparable>

Comment: if it doesn't extends it won't compile.

Comment: `List<? extends Comparable>` refers to the raw type `Comparable` and still doesn’t guaranty that the operation will succeed. E.g. try it with `List<? extends Comparable> list=Arrays.asList("foo", 42)`…

Answer (score 5):

If you are confident, that all elements of the list are mutually comparable, that is, they are not only implementing `Comparable`, but also `Comparable<CommonBaseType>`, e.g. while `String` and `Integer` instances are `Comparable`, you can’t compare a `String` with an `Integer` and must not have instances of both types in your list, then you can bypass the compile-time checking using

```
objects.sort(null);
```

of course, with all consequences of bypassing the compile time type checks.